# Subtract Two Arrays to Get A New Array in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark. 
I can sum, subtract or multiply arrays in python Pandas&Numpy. But I am having difficulty doing something similar in Spark (python). I am on Databricks.

For example this kind of approach is giving a huge error message which I don't want to copy paste here:

`differencer=udf(lambda x,y: x-y, ArrayType(FloatType()))`

`df.withColumn('difference', differencer('Array1', 'Array2'))`

Schema looks like this:

```
root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- num: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- part: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- result: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Array1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: float (containsNull = true)
 |-- Array2: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: float (containsNull = true)
```

I just want to create a new column subtracting those 2 array columns. Actually, I will get the `RMSE` between them. But I think I can handle it once I learn how to get this difference.

Arrays look like this(I am just typing in some integers):

`Array1_row1[5, 4, 2, 4, 3]`
`Array2_row1[4, 3, 1, 2, 1]`

So the resulting array for row1 should be:
`DiffCol_row1[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]`

Thanks for suggestions or giving directions. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `zip_arrays` and `transform`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [([5, 4, 2, 4, 3], [4, 3, 1, 2, 1])], ("array1", "array2")
) 

df.withColumn(
    "array3", 
    expr("transform(arrays_zip(array1, array2), x -> x.array1 - x.array2)")
).show()                                                                         
# +---------------+---------------+---------------+       
# |         array1|         array2|         array3|
# +---------------+---------------+---------------+
# |[5, 4, 2, 4, 3]|[4, 3, 1, 2, 1]|[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]|
# +---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

A valid `udf` would require an equivalent logic, i.e.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf("array<double>")
def differencer(xs, ys):
    if xs and ys:
        return [float(x - y) for x, y in zip(xs, ys)]

df.withColumn("array3", differencer("array1", "array2")).show()
# +---------------+---------------+--------------------+
# |         array1|         array2|              array3|
# +---------------+---------------+--------------------+
# |[5, 4, 2, 4, 3]|[4, 3, 1, 2, 1]|[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2...|
# +---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you @user11406020 for the response. `arrays_zip` is nice! I started reading `pyspark.sql.functions` and it is super useful. Thanks a million. Why did you downvote the question? Was it a poor explanation or a bad question?

Comment: @user11406020 what is the purpose of the `@udf("array<double>")`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip_with` (since Spark 2.4):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [([5, 4, 2, 4, 3], [4, 3, 1, 2, 1])], ("array1", "array2")
) 

df.withColumn(
    "array3", 
    expr("zip_with(array1, array2, (x, y) -> x - y)")
).show()                                                                         
# +---------------+---------------+---------------+       
# |         array1|         array2|         array3|
# +---------------+---------------+---------------+
# |[5, 4, 2, 4, 3]|[4, 3, 1, 2, 1]|[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]|
# +---------------+---------------+---------------+
```