# How to I perform operations on arrays in Pyspark without explode

Tags: arrays, pyspark

How can I perform an array operation in Pyspark without using explode?

I want to take one ArrayType column, which has array [2,4] and subtract another ArrayType column which has array [1,1]. I just want to subtract the columns element-wise, so the resulting column would be [1,3].

Thanks,
Christie

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55832763/14978104 see this answer for a potential solution - it uses the udf decorator to perform a comprehension on the arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`zip_with`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.zip_with.html#pyspark-sql-functions-zip-with) function available in pyspark. You can use it in 2 ways as shown in the following example.

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([([2, 4], [1, 1])]). \
    toDF(['arrcol1', 'arrcol2']). \
    withColumn('col1_minus_col2', func.zip_with('arrcol1', 'arrcol2', lambda x, y: x - y)). \
    withColumn('col1_minus_col2_2', func.expr('zip_with(arrcol1, arrcol2, (x, y) -> x - y)')). \
    show()

# +-------+-------+---------------+-----------------+
# |arrcol1|arrcol2|col1_minus_col2|col1_minus_col2_2|
# +-------+-------+---------------+-----------------+
# | [2, 4]| [1, 1]|         [1, 3]|           [1, 3]|
# +-------+-------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the -> sign?  Is it another way to do a lambda function? I see it all the time and don't know how it actually functions.

Comment: @ChristianneGreer it's a lambda function equivalent. *(variables) -> (operation with stated variables)*